# bcrypt.compare always return false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I want to create a login with jwt but bcrypt compare does not work.
I connected node to my db and put the db object in the req.
The type of req.body.password and user.passwordHash is in bouth cases string.

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const joi = require('joi');
const authHelper = require('./authHelper');

const router = express.Router();


router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
const schema = {
    email: joi.string().email().min(7).max(50).required(),
    password: joi.string().regex(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$/).required()
};

joi.validate(req.body, schema, (err) => {
    if(err)
        return next(new Error('Invalid field: password 7 to 15 (one number, one specail character)'));

    req.db.collection.findOne({ type: 'USER_TYPE', email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
        if(err)
            return next(err);
        if(!user)
            return next(new Error('User was not found'));

        bcrypt.compare(user.passwordHash, req.body.password, (err, match) => {
            if(match) {
                try {
                    const token = jwt.encode({
                        authorized: true, 
                        sessionIP: req.ip, 
                        sessionUA: req.headers['user-agent'], 
                        userId: user._id.toHexString(), 
                        displayName: user.displayName
                    }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

                    res.status(201).json({
                        displayName: user.displayName,
                        userId: user._id,
                        token: token,
                        msg: 'Authorized'
                    });
                }
                catch(err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
            }
            else {
                return next(new Error('Wrong password'));
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

I hope you can solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`bcrypt.compare`'s first parameter is the unhashed pasword from the user, the second parameter is the hash.:

```js
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.passwordHash, (err, match) => {
```

Comment: are you sure that you saved the user before.